# Is it a possible vulnerability / GDPR violation if basic profile of users are enumerable through the URL?

Tags: vulnerability, gdpr, user-enumeration

If a website uses an auto-incrementing user-id in its url – `/users/1`, `/users/2` to showcase public user profiles (just the name + photo / avatar)  is it considered a possible vulnerability?

Comment: We cannot comment on whether anything might violate regulations. That's more of a legal question requiring interpretation.

Comment: Have you considered that this site does exactly what you describe? https://security.stackexchange.com/users/225626/

Answer (score -4):

From GDPR PII Definition:

> ‘personal data’ means any information relating to an identified or
>   identifiable natural person (‘data subject’); an identifiable natural
>   person is one who can be identified, directly or indirectly, in
>   particular by reference to an identifier such as a name, an
>   identification number, location data, an online identifier or to one
>   or more factors specific to the physical, physiological, genetic,
>   mental, economic, cultural or social identity of that natural person;

Which means, that you should create some kind of notification, that will notify a user that the data he is submitting to the website are publicly accessible. If not, then you violated GDPR.

Comment: This is not an answer at all to what was asked